# Android:can you detect which way the finger is facing when a touch happens?

Tags: android, touch

I'm developing an application where the phone is used as a playmat of sorts.

one player will be standing on the top of the phone the other on the bottom.

Is there a way to detect if the touch that happened came from the finger of the player on top or the bottom? maybe a library that can use the proximity sensor?

I know this is probably impossible and I certainly haven't found anything while searching, but I just thought I'd ask in case anyone knows of a library I haven't found.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: I don't think that's possible. And even if that's possible you should not rely on such because it would be buggy, instead you should try and come up with a logic of some sort that can identify what you are trying to do

Comment: [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) is probably what you need. Here is the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html)

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this... I'm pretty sure you could achieve whatever it is you want by 1. setting regions that can be touched (and not), 2. the direction of the touch gestures or 3. putting a limit on the number of fingers that can touch the screen at a given time.

Comment: @Joshua no I know about gesture detector, I'm not trying to detect a slide (though that's probably what I'll have to do) or a swipe or something, I'm trying to detect the facing of the user's finger when the user clicks

Comment: @IsaacMartin @ Ezio I just thought it would look cool if the app could detect which player clicked on a button and then sent the results to their result bar, I guess I can do it with a slide towards the player as an alternative, but still it would be nicer if you could do it with just a click instead of slide :)